# maven-compiler-plugin 3.0 broken

Tags: eclipse, maven, groovy

I have a groovy-only project that I was building with gmaven, but wanted to switch it over to using the groovy eclipse compiler.

So I followed the info [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Groovy-Eclipse+compiler+plugin+for+Maven). And that works.  But there's a new 3.0 version of the maven-compiler-plugin. When I switched to that version, it would show source folders being added to the list to compile, but then exit saying that everything was up to date.

So I took the sample project (bottom of the linked page) and compiled it as is...no problem.  Switching that simple project to maven-compiler-plugin v3.0...and it fails to build anything in the same way.

Is it just me?

Comment: Can you show the pom and of course the error messages etc. you get.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to your pom in the configuration section of the maven-compiler-plugin:

```
<includes>
  <include>**/*.groovy</include>
  <include>**/*.java</include>
</includes>
<testIncludes>
  <testInclude>**/*.groovy</testInclude>
  <testInclude>**/*.java</testInclude>
</testIncludes>
```

This is something that has cropped up since 3.0.